# How to compare IPV6 addresses in python

Tags: python, compare, ip-address

I am using **python --version 2.6 and Solaris 10 as a OS**

These are some valid IPV6 addresses. I have these Ip addresses as **string**.

- 2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652
- 2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652
- 2001:cdba::3257:9652

I have to **compare** all the ip and check that whether they are **representing same ipv6 address** (represented as different notation) or not. I have search a lot,and find some classes available in python 3 like ipaddress, but I can not use that as I have python 2.6 version.Is there any class available in python 2.6?

Thanks

Comment: same ipv6 what? Region? Subnet?

Comment: I have to compare all ipv6 addresses which are same and represented as different notation.

Comment: and what are these "notations"? Just these 3 in the post? Split your strings and remove leading zeros and you have uniform representation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before comparing ipaddress you can check whether they are valid ipv6 format or not, by using socket lib:

```
import socket

def is_valid_ipv6_address(address):
try:
    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, address)
except socket.error:  # not a valid address
    return False
return True
```

after validatation now you can use regular expression to compare whether they are equal or not **iterate for all the ipv6 addresses**,:

```
if(is_valid_ipv6_address(ipv6Address)):
    new_ipv6Address=re.sub(r'::[0]', '::',re.sub(r'[::]+', '::', re.sub(':[0]+:', '::', re.sub(':[0]+:', '::', ipv6Address))))
```

This will work for aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:1111:: and aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:1111:0 format as well.

Comment: I think it is good option to check whether it is a valid ip address or not then compare...

Answer (score 4):

You can use socket.

```
import socket
ip1 = "2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652"
ip2 = "2001:cdba::3257:9652"
if socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip1) == socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip2):
     print "match"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex.sub`:

```
st_arr = ['2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652', '2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652', '2001:cdba::3257:9652']

new_string_arr = [re.sub(r'[:]+', ':', re.sub(':[0]+', ':', st))) for st in st_arr]

new_string_arr
Out[63]: ['2001:cdba:3257:9652', '2001:cdba:3257:9652', '2001:cdba:3257:9652']

new_string_arr[0] == new_string_arr[1] == new_string_arr[2]
Out[64]: True
```

First the regex replaces the pattern `:[0]+` with `:` and after this since there could be multiple colons, I replaced the pattern `[:]+` with `:`.

Comment: it is not working with aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:1111:: and aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:1111:0 notation

Comment: @AnkurAnkan Your answer would, AFAICS, treat `'2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652'` and `'2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:3257:0000:9652'` the same...

Comment: @user3717431 well that format is wrong, only "consecutive sections of zeroes are replaced with a double colon (::)", replacing one section with value 0 isn't correct

Answer (score 1):

I would just use some string manipulations such as

```
def pad(addr):
    groups = addr.split(':')
    empty = None
    for i,g in enumerate(groups):
        if empty is None and len(g) == 0: empty = i
        elif len(g) < 4:
            groups[i] = '0'*(4-len(g))+g


    if empty is not None:
        groups=groups[:empty] + ['0000',]*(8-len(groups)+1) + groups[empty+1:]

    return ':'.join(groups)

if pad('2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652') == pad('2001:cdba::3257:9652'):
    print('Same!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Install  [ipaddr](https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/wiki/Using3144)

```
import ipaddr

s1="2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652"
ips=["2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652","2001:cdba::3257:9652","2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9651"]

results=[]


for i in ips:
    print ipaddr.IPv6Address(i).exploded # re adds leading zeros etc..
    if ipaddr.IPv6Address(i).exploded==s1:
        results.append(i)
print results

2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652  
2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652
2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9651
['2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652', '2001:cdba::3257:9652']
```